# Serverless Task Scheduling on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

So our project was using Hangfire to dynamically schedule tasks but keeping in mind auto scaling of server instances we decided to do away with it. I was looking for cloud native serverless solution and decided to use CloudWatch Events with Lambda. I discovered later on that there is an upper limit on the number of Rules that can be created (100 per account) and that wouldn't scale automatically. So now I'm stuck and any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

As per [CloudWatch Events documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/cloudwatch_limits_cwe.html) you can request a limit increase.

> 100 per region per account. You can request a limit increase. For
>   instructions, see AWS Service Limits.
>
> Before requesting a limit increase, examine your rules. You may have
>   multiple rules each matching to very specific events. Consider
>   broadening their scope by using fewer identifiers in your Event
>   Patterns in CloudWatch Events. In addition, a rule can invoke several
>   targets each time it matches an event. Consider adding more targets to
>   your rules.

If you're trying to create a serverless task scheduler one possible way could be:

- CloudWatch Event that triggers a lambda function every minute.
- Lambda function reads a DynamoDB table and decide which actions need to be executed at that time.
- Lambda function could dispatch the execution to other functions or services.

Comment: Yes, true. But even the limit increase would have to be up to a certain number right? Is there anyway I could do something like this in a manner that would scale automatically?

Comment: Thanks! I did think about this, but I was concerned about the number of requests that I'd be making to the DynamoDB table. I guess there's no going around that.

Comment: You can optimize that adding a cache layer (Redis in ElastiCache for example), but you'll need to balance the cost of the cache with the cost of the requests directly to DynamoDB. Don't close the door to optimization but don't optimize prematurely :)

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to do as Diego suggested, use CloudWatch Events to trigger a Lambda every minute which would query DynamoDB to check for the tasks that need to be executed.

I had some concerns regarding the data that would be fetched from dynamoDb (duplicate items in case of longer than 1 minute of execution), so decided to set the concurrency to 1 for that Lambda.

I also had some concerns regarding executing those tasks directly from that Lambda itself (timeouts and tasks at the end of a long list) so what I'm doing is pushing the tasks to SQS each separately and another Lambda is triggered by the SQS to execute those tasks parallely. So far results look good, I'll keep updating this thread if anything comes up.